# Создание класса active у ссылок

Tags: javascript

У меня есть список ссылок в html,  и мне нужно чтобы при клике на ссылку добавлять к ней класс active, но чтобы при клики на следующую ссылку класс active у предыдущей пропадал , таким образом класс active всегда был только у одной из ссылок.

Comment: А в чём сложность? Что не получается? Приведите код, даже если он не работает.

Answer (score 1):

> У меня есть список ссылок в html, и мне нужно чтобы при клике на ссылку добавлять к ней класс active, но чтобы при клики на следующую ссылку класс active у предыдущей пропадал

Предложу такой вариант...

Вешаем обработчик на родителя и далее все действия выполняем относительно его.

```js
const ou = document.querySelector('ul')
ou.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const o = e.target
  if (o.tagName != 'A') return
  e.preventDefault()
  ou.querySelector('.active')?.classList.remove('active')
  o.classList.add('active')
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href='#'>Ссылка 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Ссылка 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Ссылка 3</a></li>
</ul>
```